# How to see DHCP boot setup in wireshark?

Tags: networking, dhcp, wireshark, tftp

My client tries to boot wrong file with DHCP and I'd like to debug it.

My previous configuration was to boot with `lpxelinux.0` file but now I changed it to `pxelinux.0`. But client is still looking for `lpxelinux.0` and I wish to observe it with Wireshark.

I made a capture filter

```
ether host 08:00:27:8B:1E:19 or host 192.168.10.126
```

which includes both ethernet and ip addresses of client. I was thinking I will see entire communication with it.

Unfortunately, I see only this

[image]

As you, client requests incorrect file. But where did it take this wrong filename, how to see?

DHCP server is different machine than TFTP server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have at least three machines

- a TFTP/DHCP server,
- the DHCP client
- a capture machine.

The chances are that the capture machine is not even seeing the network traffic, so I'd think about the network configuration. Your options are

1. Connect all machines with a hub rather than a switch.
2. Connect the capture machine to a mirror port on a programmable switch.
3. Install the capture software on the TFTP/DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the capture filter

Bootp

To see all DHCP related packets in a transaction.  I think your issue is you were limiting your results to show only the Mac addresses of the devices you were trying to see, but some of the traffic is broadcast and some of the traffic won't necessarily get picked up by your filter.